# inserting a variable into a mysql database with lua

Tags: mysql, lua, lua-table

I am trying to insert a variable into a sql database.
my code looks like this:

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
env = luasql.mysql()
conn = env:connect('try','root','root123')
print(env,conn)
file=(io.open("C:\\Calls2.1.txt","r"))
otherFile = (io.open("C:\\newFile.txt","a"))
file:seek("set","0")
for line in file:lines() do
l = line
t={}
i=1
for word  in (l .. ","):gmatch("([^,]*),") do 
    print(word)
    table.insert(t, word)
    conn:execute([[insert into dealtemplatedata values('1','111',tonumber(word),word])]]) 
end
```

but nothing appears in the table.
is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Pretty sure your SQL syntax is wrong. Figure that out and then use the Lua string concatenation operator `..` to create your SQL statement.

Comment: how could I use the concatenation operator?

Comment: It depends on the SQL statement you need. This could be part of it: ` tonumber(word) .. ",'" .. word .. "'"`. I suggest you debug by printing the SQL statement to see if it makes sense.